# Weird Sharp Shadows when normal baked with cage

Tags: baking, normal-map, shadows, artifacts

[image: Example Image]

I am getting this weird sharp edges at the shadow transition when I used cage while baking them.

It didn't appear when I when cage was not used, but without cage the edges are very sharp and don't get the curvature properly, so I have to use them.

I want to know what's causing this.